# R ggplot Create violin plot on ranked data by group

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, bioinformatics

I'm little bit stuck on ggplot trying to make a figure.

So I have a data-frame which have a length = 21685

Here a little example of my data

```
x <- data.frame("Genes" = c("Gene_1","Gene_2","Gene_3","Gene_4","Gene_5",
"Gene_6","Gene_2","Gene_8","Gene_4","Gene_10"),
"Start" = c(1,1,50,400,400,500,700,700,2000,2000), 
"End" = c(10,10,200,600,600,600,1000,1000,3000,3000),
"Log2_FC"=c(-1.2,-1.2,-0.7,-0.1,-0.1,0.3,1,1,1.5,1.5),
"TPM"=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1))
```

(x is just a part of my original dataframe that I named after df)

### So I have a lot of coordinates and for each coordinates :

- A related gene (same coordinate can have several genes and different coordinates can have a gene which is already related to a given position)
- Unique Log2(FC) value per coordinates
- Unique TPM value / per coordinate / per gene (which represent the activity of this given gene related to this coordinates)

I sorted my data by "Log2_FC".

So what I'm trying to do is to plot my data by group of 1000.
To do that I make add in my data-frame another column which is

```
df$TPM_range_1000=
rep(seq(1000, 22000, by=1000), each=1000, length.out=21685)
df$TPM_range_1000<-as.factor(df$TPM_range_1000)
```

Then making my figure :

```
 (fig1<-ggplot(df, aes(x=TPM_range_1000,y=TPM))+
  geom_violin(scale = "width",adjust = .5,fill='#A4A4A4', color="darkred")+
  geom_boxplot(width=0.1) + theme_minimal()+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point",size=2,color="red",aes(shape="Mean")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
  guides(colour=guide_legend(order=1), shape=guide_legend(title=NULL, order=2)))
```

I got something like that :

[image]

So here, I have several issues... 
The first one is that all groups are = 1000 except the last one = 685. 
How can I just change the x label by the length of given group. Because here the last group is equal to 685 but for other data it can be different.

Another things, is how can I merge on same coordinates and conserve the different TPM. Because in fact my data-frame should be shorter but I don't want to loose information in TPM column because I need to plot values here.

So if someone can  help me at least for one of my problem it would be very nice.
Thank you for reading this, It's pretty tricky and not easy to explain but I tried to do my best :).

Best,

Comment: What is `df` & how does it relate to your same dataset `x`?

Comment: actually x is just an exemple of my df dataframe. But I think that my exemple is not clear enough... Thank at least to try to understand it

Answer (score 0):

I find solution for at least one of my problem. I post answer if someone needs answers. You can also give me your point of view on my solution.

So I drop duplicated based on the "start" "end" "Log2_FC" which should be unique.
And because I want to keep only one value per coordinates I compute mean of TPM for coordinates which have several TPM.

```
#Here I drop duplicates and compute mean for coordinates which have several TPM
test =as.data.frame( df %>% group_by(start,end,Log_FC) %>% summarise(TPM=mean(TPM))) 

#I order by Log_FC value
test=test[order(test$Log_FC),]

#them make group of 500. So first 500 coordinates will have lowest Log2_FC value
test$TPM_range_500=rep(seq(500, 15000, by=500), each=500,length.out=length(test[,1])) 

#To be plot as a factor
test$TPM_range_500<-as.factor(test$TPM_range_500)
```

So I got this graph :

[image]

But I still have a problem to represent my data.

My dataframe length is equal to 14470. So data :

- between 0 - 500 will be on the first group (500)
- between 13500 - 14000 will be on group 14000
- between 14000-14470 will be on the last group : 14500

But here the problem is that the last group is shorter than the other. So I want to change at least the last x label to replace by the length of the group.

Thank for you help...